# isMaster equivalent for pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I've used `cluster` in the past for running multiple instances, but would like to start using `pm2`. However, I have a process that should only run on one of the instances launched.

Is there a way to determine or identify the initially launched instance, an equivalent to `isMaster` when using `pm2`?

Comment: reading their docs it sounds like the best way is to handle it yourself. the script can look for a 'master.pid' file, and if it does not exist, assume the master role and create the file.

Comment: is there a place in their docs that specifically presents that? Not questioning, just interested in reading it.

Comment: Nothing explicit... Im mostly going on their 'stateless' recommendation in the [cluster](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/master/ADVANCED_README.md#clustering-cluster_mode) section and [stateless apps](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/master/ADVANCED_README.md#stateless-apps) section. I also searched their issues for anyone asking the same but I don't see any references anywhere to 'master' mode

Answer (score 5):

For those ones who search it, I've found this solution.

```
if (process.env && process.env.pm_id) {
    //running in pm2 
    if (process.env.pm_id % os.cpus().length !== 0) {
        return;
    }else{
        collectSysInfo();
   }
}
```

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2035#issuecomment-199815595