# Detect "master" process in iisnode

Tags: node.js, iisnode

I'm running a `node.js` app in a 32 core machine with `iisnode`. IIS creates 32 processes to use all the CPU cores effectively and uses named pipes for each process.

I need to start a small task scheduler and run some other code but only in one of the processes, I don't want the 32 processes to run the same code at the same time. As this is not a `node.js` cluster I can't use `cluster.isMaster` and I'm not aware that `iisnode` gives an ID to each process as PM2 does (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41359945/1335209)).

Is there an easy way to run some code but only in one of all the created processes? I know I could use database lock but I was hoping to find a simpler way before having to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [proper-lockfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proper-lockfile) package that worked perfectly in my case!